# Compare web service response

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, web-api-testing

I wanted to know if there are existing tools that lets us compare web service  response from 2 different calls (could be 2 different methods with same response structure OR could be call to same method hosted on 2 different endpoints)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to check if 2 responses are the same and nothing else, `string.Equals` should be fine

Comment: Do you want to compare them for testing? Or you want to compare them in the actually application you are writing.

Comment: Make each call with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and paste the responses into [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to compare them.

Comment: Be more specific about what you want to compare.  response?  status code? response headers?  Almost any file compare tool can be used if you normal the `response` whatever that means into some string representations.  Sort headers by names and values, convert binary to hex strings, etc.

Comment: I want to run different set of test cases and call the method and compare the response from 2 endpoints (or 2 different methods under same web service, which has same response structure) for all those cases to see, if there is any difference. 

At high level, even if I can simply get a true/false kind of output from compare, that should be sufficient. I don't need to know what is different.